# What's required for hydroponic farming in a container?

Tags: food, farming, hydroponics

I have a container of size L 1.8 m × W 1.86 × H 1.73. I am planning to turn this into a hydroponic container for growing cooking greens (salad etc.). The thing that concerns me is the stuff I probably need.

Besides things such as growing-lights, ventilation, water and solution supply, shelves, and temperature control, could someone please recommend, what kind of things should I consider when planning a hydroponic container?

Comment: This question is very broad. Can you add some details, perhaps what type of plants you want, how much space you have, etc?

Comment: @LShaver The space inside is L 1,8 m × W 1,86 × H 1,73. The purpose is growing cooking greens (salad etc.) The thing that concerns me is the stuff I probably need

Comment: It might help If you identify a particular hydroponic system, ebb n flow, Nutrient flow technique, deep water culture, hempy...the list is long;